# "Parameter 'crs' is required" when exporting feature collection from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm using the Earth Engine Python API to extract wind speeds at point locations for different days depending on the date associated with each point. I've written a script that (I thought) does this properly, by using the .map function and iterating over the feature collection.

However, when attempting to export the output feature collection (tried several options: to drive, to asset, to pandas via geemap) I always get the same error: "Parameter 'crs' is required". I don't see why a crs parameter is necessary as the input feature collection is a table that has no reference system associated with it. Passing in a crs parameter does not solve the problem.

Furthermore, when inspecting the output feature collection, I see that the data type for the wind_speed field is a feature collection (inside a feature collection?), not a float as I would expect.

Here is my code. I suspect there is something wrong with the final return line of my function, the way I'm using it with .Map, or perhaps my point_value variable is the wrong data type?

```
# wildfire points with date field
WF_pts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/allanbkapoor/wildfires2')

# retrieve geometry for california
ca = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States').filterMetadata('NAME', 'equals', 'California').geometry()

# clip GRIDMENT image to california geometry
GRIDMET = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET').filterBounds(ca)

# selects dataset to be mapped
windspeed = GRIDMET.select('vs')

# Clip to bounds of geometry
windspeed_ca = windspeed.map(lambda image: image.clip(ca))

# define function that gets pixels value for a single feature based on long/lat and date
def get_single_date_value(feat):
    #convert feat to ee.feature
    feature = ee.Feature(feat)
    
    #get data for that feature from date column
    date = ee.Date(feature.get('DISCOVERY_DT'))
    
    #for single date: filter image collection to just the image for the feature's date
    windImage = windspeed_ca.filterDate(date).mean()
    
    #get point value at the feature's location
    point = ee.Geometry.Point(feature.get('LONGITUDE'), feature.get('LATITUDE'))
    scale = 30
    point_value = windImage.sample(point, scale)
    
    #return point_value
    return feature.set({'wind_speed': point_value})

#map the function over the feature collection
WF_pts_wind = WF_pts.map(get_single_date_value)
```

Comment: The docs state `ee.Image.sample` method returns a `FeatureCollection`.  The `sample` method requires a CRS, try: `windImage.sample(point, scale, 'EPSG:4326')`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `windImage.sample(point, scale, 'EPSG:4326')`  and `windImage.sample(point, scale, projection='EPSG:4326')` Now I can run the script without any error message but when I try to export to drive `task_wind = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection=WF_pts_wind, description='Wind_test', fileFormat='CSV')` it fails with a similar error message in the Task manager: "Projection: Parameter 'crs' is required" so I'm not sure if thats the issue

Comment: You still need to extract the specific property from the sampled point using `ee.FeatureCollection.get("name_of_property")`. Also, I don't see why you need convert `feat` to `ee.Feature`?

Comment: @user2856 I tried "crs" and it didn't understand that parameter. From the docs I saw the parameter name is actually "projection" and it requires a ee.projection object. I tried that and I am no longer getting that error (although the script is still not working correctly per my comment above). I'll add this as part of the solution once other issues are sorted.

Comment: @malin-fischer good call. When I look at the properties for the feature collection I see `{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'columns': {'vs': 'Float'},
 'properties': {'band_order': ['vs']},
 'features': []}` - how do I access the properties for ? I want the value from 'vs' and tried `val = point_value.get("vs")` but this is returning "None" when tested for a single point.

Comment: Try using `val = point_value.first().get("vs")` instead? Also, there might be no image data available for this point. It's hard to evaluate without access to the point data though.

Comment: @malin-fischer Including .first() throws an error. I also tried `.getNumber()` instead of just `.get()`. I know that there is image data for the test point by viewing `windImage` and picking a point that is within its bounds. I can see from calling `point_value.getInfo()` that there is 'vs' column and a 'float' column inside the object, I just don't know how to get at it.  I've made the point data public - I would very much appreciate if you could test it out, as I've hit a wall on this.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error mentioned in the question title, I modified the code to refer to a ee.projection object:

```
#get point value at the feature's location
coordinates = [feat.get('LATITUDE'),feat.get('LONGITUDE')]
projection_obj = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326')
point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords=coordinates, proj=projection_obj)
```

While this addressed the projection error issue, it does not address the output data type issue, which is seperate.